# Cookie signed - undefined method 'signed'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In Application Controller I have a method current_user with if statement if cookies.signed[:user_id]. The method works all the time but today I created new controller and route and it throw me an error

```
undefined method `signed' for nil:NilClass
```

This is the Application Controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

  before_action :current_user

  protected
  def current_user
    if cookies.signed[:user_id] && User.find(cookies.signed[:user_id])
      @current_user = User.find(cookies.signed[:user_id])
    end
  end
end
```

And this is the server log:

```
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 23ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms) 

NoMethodError (undefined method `signed' for nil:NilClass):

app/controllers/application_controller.rb:18:in `current_user'
  Rendering /Users/Dudis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /Users/Dudis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/Dudis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (4.5ms)
  Rendering /Users/Dudis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/Dudis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendering /Users/Dudis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/Dudis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/Dudis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (187.4ms)
```

Any suggestions why it does not work anymore? I didn't make any update in the app.

Comment: Does that new controller have method `cookies`, by any chance?

Comment: oh yea, it does.. that's the problem! I wanted to create a page called "cookies". Wohooo.. thank you!

Comment: @sergioTulentsev you can post it as answer and I will upvote and mark correct - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen from the error, method `cookies` returns nil. AFAIK, rails' implementation should not do that even if you don't have any cookies. Which leads me to the thought that it's not rails' version that is running. If I were to guess, you have a method `cookies` in that controller (*confirmed in comments*).

Answer (score 0):

`cookies` is nil `undefined method signed for nil:NilClass (nil.signed)`